# Extend UIScrollViewDelegate and have all viewControllers conform possible?

Tags: swift, generics, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift2

I have a parentViewController that contains a childViewController in it. The childViewController has a UICollectionView. I'd like to observe the scroll and have it conform to another protocol to speak to the parentViewController. I can get this to work for the scroll if I call the method in the UICollectionViewDelegate, but I want to be able to have it across any generic ViewController that conforms to the delegate that has a scrollView inside of it. Is this possible?

Code Below:

```
protocol HomeScrollDelegate: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func showButtons()
    func hideButtons()
    weak var homeScrollDelegate: HomeScrollDelegate? { get set }
}

extension HomeScrollDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        if targetContentOffset.memory.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            homeScrollDelegate?.hideButtons()
        } else {
            homeScrollDelegate?.showButtons()
        }
    }
}

class HomeCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var homeDelegate: HomeScrollDelegate?
    etc etc
}

extension HomeCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    weak var homeScrollDelegate: HomeScrollDelegate? {
        get {
            return self.homeScrollDelegate
        }
        set {
            self.homeScrollDelegate = homeDelegate
        }
     }

    func showButtons() {}
    func hideButtons() {}
}
```

}

**ParentViewController**

```
// set childViewController.homeDelegate = self when creating children

extension ParentViewController: HomeScrollDelegate {
    weak var homeScrollDelegate: HomeScrollDelegate? {
        get {
            return self.homeScrollDelegate
        }
        set {
             if let homeController = UIViewController() as? HomeCollectionViewController {
                self.homeScrollDelegate = homeController.homeDelegate
            }

        }
    }

    func showButtons() {
         // show buttons
     }

    func hideButtons() {
        // hide Buttons
    } 
}
```

None of this gets called. I feel like I'm doing something terribly incorrect.

Below is code that works great, but I want something slightly more generic. I know I can easily set up a protocol and just have any viewcontroller that needs to, conform to it like so:

```
protocol HomeScrollDelegate {
    func showButtons()
    func hideButtons()
}

class HomeCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var homeDelegate: HomeScrollDelegate?
    etc etc
}

extension HomeCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        if targetContentOffset.memory.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
             homeScrollDelegate?.hideButtons()
        } else {
            homeScrollDelegate?.showButtons()
        }
    }     
}
```

**ParentViewController**

```
extension ParentViewController: HomeScrollDelegate {
    func showButtons() {
         // show buttons
     }

    func hideButtons() {
        // hide Buttons
    } 
}
```

My goal in doing this is so that I don't have to override `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:_:_:)` in every UIScrollView delegate because I will have other childViewControllers that are not UICollectionViews but will have scrollViews.

Comment: Did you find any useful method for this?